# Handling a repeating fieldset in Drupal 6

Tags: forms, drupal-6

Firstly, I'm new to this project and its original development was outsourced. And boy, the project is a mess of work-arounds and non-Drupal implementations for nearly everything. This project is impossible to upgrade without significant work across every custom module. Where the developer(s) could've used CCK to handle 95% of the work they did they added many tables to the database and used Drupal forms to populate them instead.

Our client wants a new "gallery" management interface to one of these special tables. We need a way to have a repeating fieldset like:

```
gallery[0][image] // can be either link or url
gallery[0][caption]
```

Drupal 6 doesn't support repeating fields out of the box, so it looks like I have to either: install a module, or come up with a jury-rigged solution myself. But from what I've seen of Drupal it looks like I should be able to implement this with a regular form and some Javascript, if I do it right.

```
// Just an example, this isn't working code.
$index = 0;

foreach ($gallery as $id => $data) {
  $form['gallery'][$index]['id'] = array(
    '#type'  => 'hidden',
    '#value' => $id,
  );

  $form['gallery'][$index]['image'] = array(
    '#type' => 'upload',
  );

  $form['gallery'][$index]['caption'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textbox',
    '#value' => $data['caption']
  );

  $form['gallery'][$index]['delete'] = array();

  $index += 1;
}
```

Yet how could I tie a form similar to this to a Javascript "Add more" link that ties into the form state? And how do I handle the result of such form input?

Answer (score 1):

You can add dynamic form elements using AHAH. See an example with dynamic poll options at the end of this tutorial: http://drupalsn.com/learn-drupal/drupal-tutorials/getting-going-ahah-and-drupal-6

Comment: That's been pretty hard to find. I'll have to give it a try.